# Disabling jquery submit button until all the form inputs is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disabling jquery submit button until all the form inputs is filled.

Am working with Jquery and I have been trying to implement disabling form submission button until the whole form inputs are filled. i have tried  most solution found here but it does not solve the issue.  Thanks

```js
$('.postbtn_video').click(function() {

  var element = $(this);
  var ID = element.attr('id');

  var msg = $('#status').val();
  var title = $('#title').val();
  var video = $('#video').val();
  var stat = $('#stat').val();

  if (title == "") {

    alert('Please Enter video Post Title?');

  } else if (msg == "") {
    alert('Please Enter Video Post Description');

  } else if (video == "") {
    alert('Enter Youtube Video Link');


  } else if (stat == "") {
    alert('Select Status');

  } else {

    var postData = "post=" + msg + "&title=" + title + "&video=" + video + "&stat=" + stat;

    $("#loader").show();
    $("#loader").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Update...</span>');

    $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: "posts.php",
      data: postData,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {

        $("ul#updatepost").prepend(html);
        $("ul#updatepost li:first").slideDown("slow");
        $('#status').val('');
        $('#loader').hide();

      }

    });

  }

  return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" name="statusform">
  <label>Video Post Title </label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Post Title">

  <p></p>

  <label>Video Post Description</label>
  <textarea style="width:100%" name="status" class="status form-control" id="status" placeholder="Share what you like " title="What's on your mind?">
    </textarea>

  <label>Youtube Video Link</label>
  <input style="width:100%" name="video" class="form-control" id="video" placeholder="Youtube Video Link">



  <label>status</label>
  <select style="width:100%" name="stat" class="form-control" id="stat">
    <option value="ok">ok</option>
  </select>

  <p></p>

  <input name="post" type="submit" value="Share Video Updates" class="postbtn_video" style="background:black;color:white; height:30px;float:left" />

</form>
```

Comment: add `disabled` attribute to the `input[type='submit']` then on your input fields put a function on the `onblur()` to check to whether all the input fields are filled if yes remove `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly apply `disabled="disabled"` to the button:

```
<input name="post" type="submit" value="Share Video Updates" class="postbtn_video" disabled="disabled" />
```

Secondly, you need a function which will check each field is empty or not!

Check below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {
                
        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
if(!empty){ // this will only check next inputs if empty is false, but once its set to true no further check will be made
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
}
        });
        if (empty) {
            $('.postbtn_video').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('.postbtn_video').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post" name="statusform">
    <label>Video Post Title </label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Post Title">

    <p></p>

    <label>Video Post Description</label>
    <textarea style="width:100%" name="status" class="status form-control" id="status" placeholder="Share what you like " title="What's on your mind?"></textarea>

    <label>Youtube Video Link</label>
    <input style="width:100%" name="video" class="form-control" id="video" placeholder="Youtube Video Link">



    <label>status</label>
    <select style="width:100%" name="stat" class="form-control" id="stat">
        <option value="ok">ok</option>
    </select>

    <p></p>

    <input name="post" type="submit" value="Share Video Updates" class="postbtn_video" disabled="disabled" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add a disabled property to you `input` button by default like:

`<input disabled name="post" type="submit" value="Share Video Updates" class="postbtn_video" style="background:black;color:white; height:30px;float:left" />`

then in your jquery you need fire up a validate function that will check for all the inputs and if they are not empty you can simply remove the `disabled` property from your `input` button like:

```
 $(document).on('keyup', "input:not([type='submit']", function () {

          //set it to true by default
          var valid = true;

     //getting all the inputs except input submit
      var inputTextboxes = $("input:not([type='submit'])");

      inputTextboxes.each(function(e) {

     //it enters this only if the valid is true for any one value, if valid is set to false at any point it won't check it for next inputs - works for first time
    if (valid != false){

        if ($(this).val()) {
          valid = true;
        }else{
          valid = false;
        }
    }
else{
    break; //breaks the loop
     }
      });

      if (valid) {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
      } else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Think your answer is better than mine. it exposes the valid content attribute for manipulation.However, is prop() depreciated? I thought we are now supposed to use attr()

Comment: @blayderunner123 `.prop()` is not deprecated and neither the `.attr()` as they both serve different purposes. `.prop()` is used to pick properties (only the ones that browser recognizes) while `.attr()` is used to pick attributes (including the custom ones). These are two different things. and using `.attr()` will be slightly slower too. there are some good answers to this on StackOverflow do have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. you can manipulated the Form Disabled attribute:

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

//check all check all input elements to see if they are check-boxes
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
//If the input is a check-box run script else skip over
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
    //If it is a check-box ensure the box is unchecked
    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  //define Element by ID and create variable
    var $checked = $('#field_human');

  //define default state for attribute before handler function trigger
  $("#submit").attr("disabled", !$checked.checked)
  //On element handler trigger define function to execute each time handler is triggered
  $checked.click(function()
  {
      //State to define instance on method 
      if ($checked.prop('checked'))
      {
          //return true
          //remove element attribute state 'disabled'
          $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
      if($('#contactForm input').val() != '')
      {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
      
      else {
          //return false
          //set element attribute state 'disabled'
          $("#submit").attr("disabled", !$checked.checked);
      }
      //return to ready-state to wait for handler to trigger again
      return;
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputblk" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Input Block</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input name="inputblk" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="human" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Are You <strong><u>Human</u>?</strong></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="field_human" class="field_human" type="checkbox" name="human" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
      <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block btn-lg">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st:
inputs that you think are required, make it required! like below:

`<input style="width:100%" name="video" class="form-control" id="video" placeholder="Youtube Video Link" required >`

2nd:
Make your selection based on this attribute and check if values of these inputs are not empty. Disable the submit button if so.

3rd:
Make event listener to all inputs that have required attribute to listen user inputs.

something like this:

```
var l = $("[required='']");
function enableSubmit(l) {
    if (l.length == 0) {
        $("[name=post]").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        for (var m = 0; m < l.length; m++) {
            if (l[m].value.length == 0) {
                $("[name=post]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                return;
            }
        }
        $("[name=post]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
for (var m = 0; m < l.length; m++) {
    l[m].addEventListener('input', function () {
        enableSubmit(l);
    });
}
```